# Getting .NET Framework version in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, version

Anyone know the `<%=  %>` or `Response.Write()` code for getting the version of .Net my web app is running on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.Environment.Version` will give you that.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion
```